# помогите записать координаты от 1 до 180 и -179 до -1

Tags: c++, qt

Не могу сообразить, как записать координаты  xi в таком порядке: 0 до 180 -179 до -1.

```
                #define MAX_X 360
                #define MAX_Y 180

                struct MF {
                  long int recCnt;
                  float data[MAX_Y][MAX_X]; 
                }; 

                float max = mf.data[0][0];
                float min = mf.data[0][0];
                float sum = 0;
                int n = 0;
                
                for (int yi = 0; yi < MAX_Y; yi++) {
                    for (int xi = 0; xi < MAX_X; xi++) {
                        //для среднего значения
                        sum += mf.data[yi][xi];
                        n++;
                        
                        //нахожу максимальное и минимальное значение
                        if (mf.data[yi][xi] > max) {
                            max = mf.data[yi][xi];
                        }
                        if (mf.data[yi][xi] < min) {
                            min = mf.data[yi][xi];
                        }
                        
                        qDebug() << xi;
                        
                        out << yi << ";" << xi << ";" << endl; // ---- неправильно, подумать как распределить
                        
                    }
                }
```

сейчас выводит просто числа от 0 до 360
[image: координаты]

Comment: а как по вашей логике полный круг в 360 градусов делится на на ваши 2 диапазона?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как будто бы вот так

```
out << yi << ";" << xi - 360 * (xi > 180) << ";" << endl;
```

Comment: сработало, спасибо!)

Comment: для спасибов тут галочка и стрелочка вверх слева от ответа :)